# C# - Automatically pass method call to method of object with same signature

Tags: c#, wpf, rectangles

I would like to create a custom `Rectangle` in C# WPF, but it is not possible to inherit from `Rectangle`. So basically what I have to do is to copy the methods from `Rectangle` I need and pass them to a `Rectangle`-Object I keep in my custom `Rectangle`-class, like this:

```
private double _width;
public double Width
{
    get => _width;
    set
    {
        _width = value;
        _rectangle.Width = _width;
    }
}
private double _height;
public double Height
{
    get => _height;
    set
    {
        _height = value;
        _rectangle.Height = _height;
    }
}
private Brush _stroke;
public Brush Stroke
{
    get => _stroke;
    set
    {
        _stroke = value;
        _rectangle.Stroke = _stroke;
    }
}
private int _strokeThickness;
public int StrokeThickness
{
    get => _strokeThickness;
    set
    {
        _strokeThickness = value;
        _rectangle.StrokeThickness = _strokeThickness;
    }
}
private Brush _fill;
public Brush Fill
{
    get => _fill;
    set
    {
        _fill = value;
        _rectangle.Fill = _fill;
    }
}
private bool _focusable;
public bool Focusable
{
    get => _focusable;
    set
    {
        _focusable = value;
        _rectangle.Focusable = _focusable;
    }
}
```

Is there a language feature in C# .NET that does this for me so I don't have to write everything by hand?

Comment: Sounds like an XY-problem. Why are you trying to inherit/mimic WPF's `Rectangle`?

Comment: Resharper can: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Code_Generation__Delegating_Members.html

Comment: What is an `XY Problem`? I mimic the behaviour because I would like to implement some custom things (like snapping rectangles to each other in a `Canvas`) I thought `delegates` are what I need but it seems like that's only some kind of method-passing.

Comment: Have you considered creating [Extension Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) to extend behaviors of the `Rectangle` instead of having to create a new class?

Comment: @vinicius.ras I did, but extension methods are only static and I need a context for things I would like to implement (for example if a rectangle was recently snapped onto another rectangle).
@LennartStoop Looks like, Resharper only generates the code for me but the `.cs` file still gets messy and there is no kind of abbreviation for that stuff.

Comment: I'm not so sure why Microsoft had `sealed` the class, but can't things like snapping rectangles be implemented using external code? I believe, it is possible to extract the bevahiour you need into another class ([Single Responsibility Principle](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/basic-programming-principles/)).

Comment: You could instead inherit from `Shape` though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No in the native language there is not. Probably because this usually is not what you want.

Sealed classes are sealed with a reason.

In your example I don't see any added properties so maybe extension methods is the way to go?

Also I see you have a field for every property and a field `_rectangle`. Why do you do that. You could just return `_rectangle.width` in the getter.